# Unexpected results dilating images with OpenCV for Python

Tags: python-3.x, computer-vision

I'm trying to perform some morphological transformations and not getting the results I'm expecting.

The goal is to dilate an alpha map and make it gray. However, it seems to destroy fine details rather than expand on them. My dilations are also skewed vertically.

Am I misunderstanding what dilation does? My code and results are below.

```
    for layer in img:
    rand_dilate_kernel = random.randrange(2, 8)
    rand_iters = random.randrange(10, 50)
    dilate_kernel = np.ones((rand_dilate_kernel, rand_dilate_kernel), np.uint8)
    layer_pre_di = layer
    for i in np.nditer(layer_pre_di, op_flags=['readwrite']):
        if i == 0:
            i[...] = 0
        else:
            i[...] = 255

    dilation = cv2.dilate(layer_pre_di, dilate_kernel, iterations=rand_iters)

    for i in np.nditer(dilation, op_flags=['readwrite']):
        if i == 0:
            i[...] = 0
        elif i == 255:
            i[...] = 127
        else:
            i[...] = 127
```

Input:
[image: alpha]

Output:
[image: result]

Comment: This is consistent with dilating using vertical lines. I'm not familiar with using `img` as a range to iterate over, but it it's a 3D array, and you're applying this to each slice `[i,:,:]`, and the slice then has a shape `(1,N,M)`, then your kernel may be interpreted as spanning the wrong dimensions? Try creating a 3D kernel, see if that changes anything.

Comment: Other than that: (1) There is no need for setting all values to 0 or 255 before applying the dilation. Dilation works on grey values. You can choose to set them to 0 and 127 before or after the dilation. But one iteration through the image is enough. (2) Iterating the dilation with a square kernel gives the same result as applying one pass of a larger kernel. If OpenCV implements the operation correctly, doing one pass will be a lot faster.

Comment: Thanks Chris I'll give that a try. The value setting is for a different reason which isn't immediately clear in this code snippet.

Comment: Chris I was able to solve my issue, you got me pointed in the right direction.

My issue was that my kernel was of shape (2, 2, 1) but my layers were shaped (1, 320, 320). I solved the issue by reshaping my arrays for the transformation and reshaping them back afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

My issue was that my kernel was of shape (2, 2, 1) but my layers were shaped (1, 320, 320). I solved the issue by reshaping my arrays for the transformation and reshaping them back afterwards.